# Nginx http to https redirects download empty file instead

Tags: nginx, centos7, 301-redirect

Im trying to redirect my `Laravel+vuejs+nuxtjs` project from **http** to **https** but when I enter **http://example.com** or **http://www.example.com** an empty file being downloaded instead

**What have I done so far :**

1- Commenting `default_type application/octet-stream` and adding `default_type text/html` instead in nginx.conf

2-defining `types { } default_type "text/plain";` in `location /{}` of the example.com.conf

3-nginx redirect with the code below

```
server{
  listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

4- tried to redirect it with a .php file with the following example.com.conf file:

```
       server {
          listen 37.152.191.249:80;
          server_name www.example.com example.com;

         access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.bytes bytes;
        access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.log combined;
        error_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.error.log error;

        root /home/example/public_html/;
        index index.php;

   location / {
types { } default_type "text/plain";
    try_files                       $uri $uri/  /index.php?$query_string;

}

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
    include                         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size             16k;
    fastcgi_buffers                 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
   fastcgi_send_timeout            300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            300;
}


        location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {deny all;return 404;}

        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=/home/example/public_html;
}
```

the index.php in public_html code :

```
    $location = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $location);
    exit;
```

**None of the above worked and the problem still presist.**

+Current Configurations :

**nginx -t report :**

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**example.com.ssl.conf :**

```
server{
  listen xx.xx.xx.xx:443 http2 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.com.bundle;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EE3CDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA!RC4:EECDH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eN$
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

       ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
       ssl_session_timeout 60m;
       return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
       server {
          listen xx.xx.xx.xx:443 http2 ssl;
          server_name www.example.com;

         access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.bytes bytes;
        access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.log combined;
        error_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com.error.log error;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/example.com.bundle;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA!RC4:EECDH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eN$
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 60m;

        root /home/example/core/public/;
        index index.php;

   location / {
  proxy_set_header                Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_http_version              1.1;
    proxy_pass                      https://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000$uri;
    proxy_intercept_errors          on;# In order to use error_page directive this needs to be on
    error_page                      404 = @php;
}

location @php {
    try_files                       $uri $uri/  /index.php?$query_string;

}

location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
    include                         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size             16k;
    fastcgi_buffers                 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
   fastcgi_send_timeout            300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            300;
}


        location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {deny all;return 404;}

        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=/home/example/public_html;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                default_type "text/plain";
                alias /usr/local/apache/autossl_tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        }

        location /.well-known/pki-validation {
                default_type "text/plain";
                alias /usr/local/apache/autossl_tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        }
}
```

**Current example.com.conf** :

```
server{
  listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I have not added the nginx -T report since it shows irrelevant configuration files from other websites.

Also server running multiple sites and the wordpress ones have no problem redirecting using the code provided at **#3** for redirect but when it comes to **THE** site that uses nuxtjs , I get a empty file downloaded instead.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You don't need to change MIME types at all for the redirect. Are you sure your `example.com.conf` has correct `server_name`? Is the `example.com.conf` file visible in `nginx -T` output?

Comment: Yes it is visible in nginx -T I have checked it numors times.(after each change).and I agree with you , changing MIME type is not needed but was worth a shot that it may gets passed to php-fpm instead of getting downloaded

Comment: Are you sure the IP address in `listen` directive is correct? If the address doesn't match, then nginx won't use this virtual host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied one of my wordpress nginx config and replaced the **xxx** part with **domain name** and **yyy** with **server IP**

```
server {
        listen yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:80;
        server_name xxx.com  www.xxx.com;
  return 301 https://xxx$request_uri;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;

                location ~.*\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
                        expires max;
                }

                location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                                return  404;
                        }

                        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
                        fastcgi_index   index.php;
                        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                }

        }

        location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {deny all;return 404;}


        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=/home/domainname/public_html;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                default_type "text/plain";
                alias /usr/local/apache/autossl_tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        }

        location /.well-known/pki-validation {
                default_type "text/plain";
                alias /usr/local/apache/autossl_tmp/.well-known/acme-challenge;
        }
}
```

It gets redirected to https without downloading anything, I've rewinded all the changes I had done to nginx and php-fpm to their default.

Now its working But why ?

after playing around noticed changing the location of the working nginx config to `location ~ \.php$` (the one I was using before) will make the issue return.thats it!

No further investigation of why `location ~ \.php$` does **NOT** work but `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)` does.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Winston Krauss @serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/844433/1039393) contributed to the same topic on April-2017.
The location ~ modifier

> `[^/]\.php(/|$)`

might point to a server-configuration which doesn't contain the

> `listen 80 http2`

directive, but

> `\.php$`

does and could have affected how nginx listen on port 80.